# Can I specify locations of variables using VC linker?

Tags: linker, visual-c++

I have a VC project with hundreds of global variables and buffers placed into several source files. I want the linker to put these variables physically adjacent in the final output executable in order that I can easily clean up these variables.
I know that gcc linker can do that via a linker script. I just wonder if vc linker can also do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
#pragma section( "section-name" [, attributes] )
```

to declare a new section. Then use

```
__declspec(allocate("segname")) declarator
```

to specify in which section your global variable is placed.

I believe this is what GCC does, though haven't experimented myself in VC.

Below are MS links:

[section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx)

[allocate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bkb2w6t.aspx)

There is also another similar question on stackoverflow:

[How to place a variable at a given absolute address in memory (with Visual C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784735/how-to-place-a-variable-at-a-given-absolute-address-in-memory-with-visual-c)

Comment: This method is a little troublesome since I have to put the __declspec to all the hundreds of variables.
    For gcc linker script, it is to easy to do that, shown as below:
    
    .bss {
      __my_bss_section_start = .
      .bss(a.o)  .sbss(a.o)
      .bss(b.o)  .sbss(b.o)
      .bss(c.o)  .sbss(c.o)
    
      __my_bss_section_end = .