# How can I declare a variable at an absolute address with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, declaration, absolute

We are looking at how the linker works in one of my courses and one of the assignments is a little exercise involving the `nm` command. essentially we just want to match the type and the value printed by `nm` for each variable. for example:

```
char* B = NULL;
```

would give the address (irrelevant) then B B. I've done this successfully for all the labels we needed to except for A. I have read that this simply means the value is absolute and cannot be changed by the linker. I have experimented with many combinations involving `volatile`, `const`, `static`, define, and any thing else I could think to try, but I am presently out of ideas. I had read elsewhere that this could only be achieved by creating a linker script to do so, but that is not the case, as some of me peers have solved this with one line in C. Could any one come up with a way in C to output:

```
some address A A
...
```

Whem `nm` is called on it's object file?

Comment: So you're asking for C source code for a program such that, when `nm` is run on its compiled form, the output will include an address for a variable named "A"?

Comment: Yes, I want calling nm on the object file from the source code to output: 000000000000002a A A. The "000000000000002a" is not important however

Comment: The C language does not in any way address the question of *which* address is assigned to any particular symbol, nor the question of symbol relocation.  Everything the `nm` utility does is quite outside its scope.  Specific compilers may recognize extensions that allow you to do what you want; what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining absolute symbols in Standard C is a bit tricky. But you can use non-standard inline assembly:

```
$ cat x.c
asm (".globl A");
asm ("A = 0x42");
$ clang -c x.c
$ nm x.o
0000000000000042 A A
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't even know you could do that, guess that is why it was extra credit, thank you! Just noticed the hitchhiker reference, nice.

Comment: could also use 'A org 0x42'  to place the 'A' label at address 0x42