# Is it possible to change an adress of a variable with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have a following program:

```
int a=7;  // while &a=0x67a9
```

Is there a way to change adress of **a**, to for ex. 0xaa55?

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Comment: this is an XY problem.  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: why you need this?

Comment: No, but it is possible to create the variable at a specified location: [Create new C++ object at specific memory address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554774/create-new-c-object-at-specific-memory-address)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The addresses of local variables are registers or stack addresses. So these can even change with every call context.

---

In case you know that your hardware supports to have a value at that specific address, you can use a pointer though:

```
volatile int* pa = 0x67a9;
```

and access the value

```
std::cout << *pa << std::endl;
```