# What is the correct way to create a struct at a specific address in C?

Tags: c, mmap

C++ has a neat feature where you can create an object at a specific memory address as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554774/create-new-c-object-at-specific-memory-address).

This is particularly useful with `mmap` like so:

```
void *ptr = mmap(0, length, prot, flags, fd, offset);

A *ptrA = new (ptr) A;
```

What is the correct way to replicate this with just C-style structs? Would it just be this?

```
void *ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(A), prot, flags, fd, offset);

A *ptrA = (A*) ptr;
```

Comment: You just set the address and treat it as though it was the struct. C doesn't verify that you're using any memory correctly. Usually writing to a specific address is used to write to hardware registers.

Comment: What you have as shown, casting the the pointer returned from mmap as a pointer to the desired type, is spot on.

Comment: FYI the explicit cast in C is unnecessary as a void pointer can be assigned to a pointer variable of any type: `A *ptrA = ptr;`

Comment: @kaylum: Any object type, not any type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid because no memory usage constraints are enforced in C.

```
void *ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(A), prot, flags, fd, offset);

A *ptrA = (A*) ptr;
```

Comment: Good for answering your own questions. Note, as mentioned in the comments, `A *ptrA = ptr;` is fine without the cast as `ptr` has `void*` type and in C a pointer and be assigned to/from `void*` without a cast.